# Share one file to every virtualhost

Tags: apache, virtualhost

Is there a way to share a file to every virtualhost. Every virtualhost has a different subdomain, but I need the same file (robots.txt) on every virtualhost. Each virtualhost has different DocumentRoots, some are only proxys to another network applications.

Comment: Create it in one spot and link it in to the / directory for each host?

Comment: But I also need the file for vhost's which are proxys to web applications. Isn't there a way with some rewrite magic?